# JInput won't detect Controller Win 7 64 bit

Tags: java, jinput

I'm trying to detect a Controller device with JInput. It works fine on my Win7 32 bit PC and Java 32 bit VM. But unfortunally it doesn't find the controller, when i start the programm on a Win7 64 bit PC with Java 64 Bit VM. My code is like this:

```
private boolean init() {

    ControllerEnvironment env = new DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin();

    Controller[] cs = env.getControllers();

    for (int i = 0; i < cs.length; i++) {

        if (cs[i].getName().contains("TM3 PTT")) {
            pttController = cs[i];
        }
    }

    if (pttController == null || !pttController.poll()) {
        pttController = null;
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

Anyone has an idea, what i am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Does it use a library which loads a DLL? Is the 64-bit version of the DLL available?

Comment: Yes we started small test jar and it detected the device. But i guess not with the DirectAndRawInputEnvironmentPlugin() method, but ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment(). The problem is that it doesn't refresh the device list.

Comment: I have a similar issue, everything online suggests that it should work and that there's nothing left to do, but it doesn't detect anything.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be constructing the controller environment youself, use the static method on ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment().

See the getting started guide [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/getting-started-with-jinput/16866/view.html).

Comment: I already tested it, same effect. It's not working. It's really confusing.